# the contraction and covariant differentiation commute.

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

In *Riemannian Geometry* of Peter Petersen p71, Exercise 2.5.9. He says that for any $(1,1)$-tensor $S$, we have $tr(D_XS)=D_XtrS$. I try to prove this:
\begin{aligned}
tr(D_XS)=&\sum\limits_ig((D_XS)(E_i),E_i)\\
&=\sum\limits_i[g(D_X(S(E_i))-S(D_XE_i),E_i)]\\
&=\sum\limits_i[X(g(S(E_i),E_i))-g(S(E_i),D_XE_i)-g(S(D_XE_i),E_i)]\\
&=D_XtrS-\sum\limits_i[g(S(E_i),D_XE_i)+g(S(D_XE_i),E_i)]
\end{aligned}
But I can't get $\sum\limits_i[g(S(E_i),D_XE_i)+g(S(D_XE_i),E_i)]=0$. Can anyone solve it? More generally, can anyone show that contraction and covariant differentiation commute for all types of tensor?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $E_i$ is a coordinate field, and if $E^k$ is dual, i.e. $E^k(E_i)=\delta_i^k$, then   \begin{align*}\nabla_X S_t^t &=X(S^t_t) - S_l^t (\nabla_XE_t)^l +
S_t^l(\nabla_XE^t)_l \\&= X({\rm tr}\ S) -S_l^t X^m \Gamma_{mt}^l +
S_t^lX^m \Gamma_{ml}^t\\& =X({\rm tr}\ S)\end{align*}

Answer (score 1):

First, one needs to extend $E_i$'s in a neighbourhood to talk about their covariant derivatives in the $X$ direction. Once you have done that, your formula is true.

Since the expression $D_X(tr S)$ is tensorial, it does not depend on the choice of the extension. So let's extend them by some local vector fields satisfying $D_X E_i = 0$ at the point we want to compute (exercise: show that this is possible): now, the result follows!

Comment: Thanks! We can just select a normal frame around the point. Then I have another question: How to show $\mathcal{L}_X(trS)=tr(\mathcal{L}_XS)$?

Comment: @eulershi This is in general not possible to choose a local orthonormal frame since the metric is rarely flat: this would imply that $[E_i,E_j]=0$ and thus $\{E_i\}$ would be tangent to some coordinates in which the Riemann tensor would vanish.